# Суть объединения двух моделей в одну таблицу в Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Изучая возможности `Entity Framework` нашел интересную вещь :

*Можно создавать отдельные таблицы в БД используя 2-е связанные между собой модели*

**Теперь приведу пример кода :**

```
[Table("Mobiles")]
public class PhoneInfo
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Phone")]
    public int PhoneId { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }

    public Phone Phone { get; set; }
}

[Table("Mobiles")]
public class Phone
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Info")]
    public int PhoneId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public PhoneInfo Info { get; set; }
}
```

**Теперь объясню поподробней смысл кода :** 
Чтобы код адекватно заработал нужно чтобы эти две модели имели :

*A)* Связь "один-к-одному"

*Б)* Общий ключ

**И глядя на это встает закономерный вопрос :** А не проще ли будет проще соединить классы `PhoneInfo` и `Phones` в один , *вместо* создания непривычной и возможно даже ненужной связи "один-к-одному" ,*таким образом* работая, вместо 2-х сущностей, с одной конкретной ?

И если нам так уж хочется подчеркнуть зависимость `PhoneInfo` от  `Phone` , то будет ли уже разумней создать более понятную разработчику связь "один-ко-многим"?

*Пример почему связь один-к-одному к двум таблицам(в нашем случае двум сущностям) - не всегда хорошо :* https://habrahabr.ru/post/193380/

**Ведь** даже уже непосредственно в коде мы будем работать с этими сущностями как будто при связи "один-ко-многим" :

```
 using(MobileContext db = new MobileContext())
{
    PhoneInfo pi2 = new PhoneInfo { PhoneId = 2, Company = "Nokia", Price = 8000};       
    Phone p1 = new Phone { PhoneId = 1, Name = "Samsung Galaxy S5", Info = pi1 };
    db.Infos.Add(pi1);
    db.Phones.Add(p1);
    db.SaveChanges();
     
    foreach (Phone p in db.Phones.Include(p=>p.Info))
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) - {2}", p.Name, p.Info.Company, p.Info.Price);
}
```

**Поэтому меня больше всего интересует :** есть ли хоть несколько примеров или правил которые подтверждают ,что лучше использовать такой извращенный способ вместо привычного "один-ко-многим" или это ещё один пример синтаксического сахара ?

Ведь `Entity Framework` предоставляет такую возможность не просто так ,не так ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от требований заказчика, причин может быть несколько.
В данном случае со стороны БД, такие таблицы это как аналог в ООП, базовый класс и наследник. Т.е связанные таблицы расширяют/изменяют сведения и обработку данных из базовой таблицы.

1) Таблица "наследник", может иметь намного меньше записей и использоваться для агрегированных данных для отчетности.

2) Таблица "наследник" может быть доступна для определенных запросов(приложений), при этом не раскрывая базовую (частичный доступ)

3) Таблица наследник имеет иные триггеры

Возможно и другие варианты причин разделения на 2..N сущностей... как и наоборот из нескольких таблиц в БД возможно создать одну сущность, если таковы требования заказчика.

Подробнее можно прочитать в книге Entity Framework 6 Recipes (http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781430257882)

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно в приведенном вами случае - две сущности избыточны.

Пример когда вторая сущность нужна - хранение файлов в БД. В таком случае вынесение содержимого файла в отдельный класс позволит, к примеру, получить список файлов не загружая их содержимое.

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть как реализовать подобное (или киньте ссылку ) ,если вам несложно

Comment: @clyde замените в своем примере PhoneInfo и Phone на FileInfo и File

Comment: я хотел спросить как будет выглядеть реализация  подобного типа данных - уже нашел